# I programmatically create button that i place inside a table, i wish to add a click event to the button but failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button

My Problems -
  => When i click the button, the page just refresh and the button gone. What i want is when i click the button, i can identify the button ID and show the message.

My GridView Code -

```
  protected void initData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Button", typeof(Button));

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "Testing";
        btn.Text = "Testing";
        btn.Click +=btn_Click;
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Button"] = btn;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            BoundField bField = new BoundField();
            bField.DataField = col.ColumnName;
            bField.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
            gvTest.Columns.Add(bField);
        }
        gvTest.DataSource = dt;
        gvTest.DataBind();
    }
```

My code is as follow -

```
protected void initData()
    {
        var data = db.Courses;

        TableRow tr = new TableRow();

        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Testing";
        btn.ID = "Testing";
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
        tc.Controls.Add(btn);

        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        tbTest.Rows.Add(tr);

    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Response.Write(btn.ID);
    }
```

Comment: tbTest is a control (asp:table) that i added to the .aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing all your code, but dynamically adding controls is almost always a PITA.  One thing you have to make absolutely sure of is that you are recreating the controls on postback.  The entire control tree must be identical in order for events and viewstate to work properly.  So you need to be calling initData() as early as possible and you have to call it for postbacks as well, which is the opposite of what you do with typical ViewState-enabled controls declared in markup.

Comment: I tried to move the initData(); out from the if(isPostBack)

i can view the message now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a grid control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb907626(v=vs.100).aspx

That way, you don't have to write the HTML.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, 
 GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
 {
// Retrieve the row index stored in the 
// CommandArgument property.
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

// Retrieve the row that contains the button 
// from the Rows collection.
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

// Add code here to add the item to the shopping cart.
}

}
```

Comment: I tried to add button into GridView control, but failed.
I use table because it easy to add any control.

Comment: Please post your code for the GridView. I don't recommend tables, since you shouldn't hard code a layout.

Comment: I added my gridview code, i can't add button to my gridview